# Clang xcode code formatter puts new line

Tags: xcode, clang

I installed Clang for xcode and formatted my code with it

everything seems fine, except if the class name is too long for a property, it goes to the next line

is there a setting i can put to prevent that?

```
@property(nonatomic, strong)                            <==bad (the new line)
UITableViewDelegate *invoiceListTableViewDelegate;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSDate *lastCall;  <== good
```

here is my property file:

```
---
# BasedOnStyle:  LLVM
AccessModifierOffset: -2
ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth: 4
AlignEscapedNewlinesLeft: false
AlignTrailingComments: true
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: true
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: false
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: false
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: false
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: false
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: true
BreakConstructorInitializersBeforeComma: false
BinPackParameters: true
ColumnLimit:     250
ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine: false
DerivePointerBinding: false
ExperimentalAutoDetectBinPacking: false
IndentCaseLabels: false
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 1
NamespaceIndentation: None
ObjCSpaceBeforeProtocolList: true
PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter: 19
PenaltyBreakComment: 60
PenaltyBreakString: 1000
PenaltyBreakFirstLessLess: 120
PenaltyExcessCharacter: 1000000
PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine: 60
PointerBindsToType: false
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 1
Cpp11BracedListStyle: false
Standard:        Cpp03
IndentWidth:     2
TabWidth:        8
UseTab:          Never
BreakBeforeBraces: Attach
IndentFunctionDeclarationAfterType: false
SpacesInParentheses: false
SpacesInAngles:  false
SpaceInEmptyParentheses: false
SpacesInCStyleCastParentheses: false
SpaceAfterControlStatementKeyword: true
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
ContinuationIndentWidth: 4
...
```

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you want to ***uncheck*** the line wrapping checkbox in your Xcode "Text Editing" preferences:

[image: Line Wrapping Preference]